# Confluence REST API Authorization Failure

Tags: api, rest, curl, confluence

I am trying to use the Confluence REST API to create a page.  I am using the curl example off of the documentation found [HERE](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples#ConfluenceRESTAPIExamples-Createanewpage).  Every time I try to run a terminal command using this curl I get a response that says 'HTTP Status 401 - Basic Authentication Failure - Reason : AUTHENTICATION_DENIED'.  I see that someone else had a similar issue regarding [their C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531312/confluence-rest-api-authorization-issue), but there was never a resolution given.  Hopefully someone with experience will be able to tell me what I am doing wrong.  My curl is listed below with the sensitive parts replaced in <> format.

```
curl -u <USER>:<PASSWORD> -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"type":"page","title":"new page","space":{"key":"<PAGEKEY>"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}}' https://<SERVER>/wiki/confluence/rest/api/content/ | python -mjson.tool
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve this.  Through a combination of the answer here [How to create new page in Confluence using their REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523705/how-to-create-new-page-in-confluence-using-their-rest-api) and using a login that had the appropriate permissions.